# What is the correct general solution of $\sin x=-\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

**My attempt:**

$$\sin x=-\frac{1}{2}$$

$$x=n\pi+(-1)^{n}\sin^{-1}(-\frac{1}{2})$$

$$x=n\pi+(-1)^{n}(-\frac{\pi}{6})$$

$$x=n\pi-(-1)^{n}(\frac{\pi}{6})$$

**My book's solution:**

$$x=n\pi+(-1)^{n}(\frac{7\pi}{6})$$

Who is correct?

Comment: You may want to use `\left(\right)` instead of `()` to make grouping symbols bigger.

Comment: Write down your solution for $n=1, 2, 3, 4$. Then do the same with the solution from the book. Can you recognize something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're [both correct](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/laqbbrgdlv): for each $x\in \mathbb R$ and $k\in[-1,1]$,

$$\sin x=k\iff \text{for some }n\in\mathbb Z,\;x=n\pi+(-1)^n\alpha,$$ where $\alpha$ is ***any*** solution of $\sin \alpha=k.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Both are correct and denote the same set of solutions. To show this,

Let $A=\{n\pi-(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{6}: n\in \mathbb Z\}$ and $B=\{n\pi+(-1)^n\frac{7\pi}{6}: n\in \mathbb Z\}$.

From here, show that $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\sin x=-\frac{1}{2} \iff x=-\frac \pi 6+2k\pi \quad \lor \quad \frac {7\pi} 6+2k\pi$$

which is equivalent to both solutions indeed

- for $n=2k$

$$x=2k\pi-(-1)^{2k}\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}$$

$$x=2k\pi+(-1)^{2k}\left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)=2k\pi+\frac{7\pi}{6}$$

- for $n=2k+1$

$$x=(2k+1)\pi-(-1)^{2k+1}\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=2k\pi+\frac{7\pi}{6}$$

$$x=(2k+1)\pi+(-1)^{2k+1}\left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)=2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}$$